# How to append similar form when clicked add option?

Tags: jquery, html, css, cakephp

I want to append all the elements of form (i.e. append entire form) after clicking 'Add' button every time. I know I have to use JQuery but I have no idea how to implement it. Here is my basic code.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <legend>Work History</legend>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <?php echo $this->Form->create('Tenant', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'addTenantWorkHistories'), 'id' => 'test'));?>
       <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('company_name', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[WorkHistory][company_name]',
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('position', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[WorkHistory][position]',
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Address</label>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('street_number', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[Address][street_number]',
                        'placeholder' => 'Street Number',
                        'label' => false,
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('street', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[Address][street]',
                        'placeholder' => 'Street',
                        'label' => false,
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('unit', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[Address][unit]',
                        'placeholder' => 'Unit',
                        'label' => false,
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('city', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[Address][city]',
                        'placeholder' => 'City',
                        'label' => false,
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('state', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[Address][state_id]',
                        'placeholder' => 'State',
                        'label' => false,
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('country', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[Address][country_id]',
                        'placeholder' => 'Country',
                        'label' => false,
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('zip', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[Address][zip]',
                        'placeholder' => 'Zip',
                        'label' => false,
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date Started</label>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-inline">
           <?php echo $this->Form->input('date_started', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[WorkHistory][date_started][]',
                        'type' => 'date',
               'label' => false,
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date Ended</label>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-inline">
           <?php echo $this->Form->input('date_ended', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[WorkHistory][date_ended][]',
                        'type' => 'date',
               'label' => false,
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('current_employer', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[WorkHistory][current_employer]',
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'options' => array(
                          'yes' => 'Yes',
                           'no' => 'No'
                        ),
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <label>Contact Person</label>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('first_name', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[Contact][first_name]',
                        'placeholder' => 'First Name',
                        'label' => false,
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('last_name', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[Contact][last_name]',
                        'placeholder' => 'Last Name',
                        'label' => false,
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Phone</label>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('home', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[PhoneNumber][home]',
                        'placeholder' => 'Home',
                        'label' => false,
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('work', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[PhoneNumber][work]',
                        'label' => false,
                        'placeholder' => 'Work',
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('mobile', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[PhoneNumber][mobile]',
                        'placeholder' => 'Mobile',
                        'label' => false,
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[Contact][email]',
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('may_contact', array(
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'name' => 'data[Contact][may_contact]',
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'options' => array(
                          'yes' => 'Yes',
                           'no' => 'No'
                        ),
                        'required'
                    ));?>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" id="adding_form"></i>Add  <!--***It should do the job*** -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </di
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
      <?php echo $this->Form->button('Create', array(
                      'class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-right'
                  ));?>
      <?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

For the jquery part, I have done:

```
  <script>
    $("#adding_form").on("click", function() {
            alert('ok');
            }); 
    </script>
```

It would be very helpful if anyone could give me hints on it? (I know basics about 'append', 'appendTo and clone by the way)

Comment: Add the elements to what? They're already part of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I exactly understand from your code what your form to duplicate is, but I'm going to show you an example. Let's say your form was contained by a `div` with the class `formToDuplicate` and that you want to duplicate the form (the div and all it contains) when the user clicks on a button or something. What you need to do is to [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the form you want to duplicate and to [append to](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) where you want to append. You would do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#adding_form").on("click", function() {
        $("div.formToDuplicate:first").clone().appendTo($("#elementToAppendTo"));
    }); 
});
```

Or if you want, you can add the form before an element (see [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)):

```
$("div.formToDuplicate:first").clone().insertBefore($("#elementBeforeWhereToInsert"));
```

The above code assumes the form you want to add is the **first** `div` element having `formToDuplicate` as class. You only want to duplicate the first element, because when you add a new form, it will be a complete duplicate of your first one, thus it will also have a class `formToDuplicate`. So, if you omit `:first` in your selector, it will add all the existing forms.

[Here is a JSFiddle example to help you understand](http://jsfiddle.net/BishopBarber/4athg42j/)